# How to use mutate ifelse gether date in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use dplyr::mutate find gether date.

example
I want to find data of EDS>2020-10-01 ,but my code is fail.

```
test1 <-  data %>%
   mutate(g = ifelse(  (EDS > "2020-10-01" & `price`>0 ) | 
              (is.na(EDS) & `price`>0 ) , 1 , 0))
```

What is the right way of coding this?
Thanks!

---

Warning message:
Problem while computing `g = ifelse(...)`.
ℹ Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">"

Comment: Do you get any error?.  It is not clear what you meant by failing.  Is it giving unexpected output or an error?  Please consider to provide a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: try `as.Date("2020-10-01")`. At the moment you are testing whether EDS is greater than a _character string_, not a date. Also make sure that EDS is actually in date or date-time format, no a character column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column is `POSIXlt` class which is a list. Converting to `Date` class should work

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(EDS = as.Date(EDS), g = ifelse(  (EDS > "2020-10-01" & `price`>0 ) | 
              (is.na(EDS) & `price`>0 ) , 1 , 0))
```

Otherwise, the comparison with `character` class or `Date` class should have worked

```
> "2019-01-01" > "2020-01-01"
[1] FALSE
> "2019-01-01" > "1999-01-01"
[1] TRUE
```

---

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(EDS = c("1990-01-01", "2020-10-01", 
     "2021-10-01"), price = c(1.5, 0, 0.5))
```